# Change default Open-File operation for certain extensions

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to change the default behaviour on double-click (Left-Click) only for certain file extensions? 
For example I want `.pdf` Files to open with the dafault application automatically. As of now I have to open context menu and select `Open\Run` via `SideBarEnhacement` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it is not possible to customize the sidebar that much. Changing the behaviour of the rightclick menu with a plugin, like SideBarEnhancement does, is as far as you can go.